# Interaction between two usercontrols in WPF without using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have two `UserControls` in my application, both of them reside on the `MainWindow`. Now I need to interact between these two, so that when I click `Button` in `UserControl1`, the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` in `UserControl2` changes.

How can I achieve this without MVVM? I would love to see the MVVM solution though if it is complete cause I'm totally new to it and it is very overwhelming.

**MainWindow:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication23.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:wpfApplication23="clr-namespace:WpfApplication23">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <wpfApplication23:UserControl1/>
        <wpfApplication23:UserControl2 Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**UserControl1:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication23.UserControl1"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Change Text"
                Width="200"
                Height="80"
                Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl2:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication23.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="20"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Click Event for Button:**

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Access the TextBlock in UserControl2 and Change its Text to "Hello World"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this *without* MVVM, you will need to do the following:

1. Set up an event like "UpdateText" on the first user control, have the button's click method raise this event.

   ```
   public event Action<string> UpdateText;
   private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      // Access the TextBlock in UserControl2 and Change its Text to "Hello World"
      if (UpdateText != null)
          UpdateText("HelloWorld");
   }
   ```
2. Listen to the event in `MainWindow` that then calls a function on the second user control to update the textblock. Something like:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       myUserControl1.UpdateText += HandleUpdateText;
   }

   private void HandleUpdateText(String newText)
   {
       myUserControl2.SetText(newText);
   }
   ```

Now the **right** answer to do this would be to use MVVM, but the code sample required would be too long for StackOverflow. I will provide the steps however:

1. Set up a `DependencyProperty` on the second user control for the "Text" property, and bind to it:

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication23.UserControl2"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
       <Grid>
          <TextBox Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding ControlText}"/>
       </Grid>
   </UserControl>
   ```
2. Put an `ICommand` dependency property on the first user control that will be invoked on the button click. Bind a function to it on `MainWindow` that will set the `ControlText` property to the parameter object.

Probably not the best "First MVVM" sample, as it requires a few advanced concepts (commanding and dependency properties), but it shouldn't be *too* hard to implement.

Comment: I won't write the program for you, but if you want clarification on the MVVM side, I am happy to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: Thank you so much Bradley, how can I listen to the Event in the MainWindow?

Comment: Thanks Bradley, this is my main concern, how do I get the TextBlock inside `myUserControl2`? I think I'm finally close to a solution after hours of searching.

Comment: @Vahid You call the `SetText` method of the second user control, which then sets the text block's text property. `MainWindow` doesn't, and shouldn't, have access to the internal controls of `UserControl2`.

Comment: I just figured it out, but I the method `SetText` that I have defined for `myUserControl2` doesn't show up for it in the `MainWindow`, should I define it a different way?

Comment: oh I had defined it `private`. Thanks. Problem solved.

Comment: Is there any chance that I keep my MainWindow.cs clean? It seems a bit odd? Maybe if I used MVVM I would have a cleaner MainWindow.cs right? Any other way other than MVVM to keep it clean?

Comment: @Vahid That's right, MVVM would keep it a lot cleaner (one of the reasons to use it). I can't think of anything off the top of my head for another way to clean it up. You mentioned that MVVM was overwhelming for you; I'd be happy to chat about that with you in about an hour, maybe I can clear up some of the confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much Bradley, I would really appreciate it. I'm kinda obsessive about writing clean code, but the learning curve is very steep for me.

Comment: I happened to ask another question regarding MVVM, I've searched the similar topics I couldn't solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023551/bind-the-property-of-an-element-in-usercontrol-to-a-property-in-myviewmodel-cs

Comment: Sorry I saw your comment a few minutes late. How can we chat here? Can you give me the link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58296/discussion-between-bradleydotnet-and-vahid).

Comment: I tried my best at understanding commands in WPF but was unable to reach a result :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032572/send-commands-between-two-usercontrols-in-wpf

Comment: The answer you got was correct, but lets see if I can clarify it in chat. If I come up with enough information I"ll post a new answer to that question :)