# Bind the property of an element in UserControl to a property in MyViewModel.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

First of all, I'm very very new to the concept of MVVM. I'm even not sure what I'm asking here is even a MVVM question. So please forgive me for my mistakes I may make here.

I'm trying to `Bind` the `Foreground` property of a `TextBlock` in a `UserControl` to `TextColor` property in `MyViewModel.cs`. I also want to be able to change the `TextColor` property via code. For example by clicking a button. How can I achieve all of these.

Here is the complete non-working error-free code I've put up so far!

**MainWindow:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication23.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication23">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1 x:Name="MyControl"/>
        <Button Content="Change Color" 
            Width="200" 
            Height="30" 
            Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;    
namespace WpfApplication23
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MyViewModel();

        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Change the `TextColor` property in `MyViewModel.cs`
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication23.UserControl1"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Sample Text" Foreground="{Binding TextColor}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MyViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Brush TextColor;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        TextColor = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MyViewModel` class should declare a public `TextColor` property, not a public field (and you may rename it to `TextBrush`, because it is a Brush, not a Color). In order to be able to notify about changes of the property value, it should also implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Brush textColor = Brushes.Red;
    public Brush TextColor
    {
        get { return textColor; }
        set
        {
            textColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TextColor");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In your button click handler you may now cast the `DataContext` to your MyViewModel class, and set the property.

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
    vm.TextColor = Brushes.Blue;
}
```

An even better solution to change the color would be to bind the Button's `Command` property to an `ICommand` in your view model. You may start reading about this in the [Commanding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you so much Clemens. Can I ask you about the role of `RaisePropertyChanged`? What does it do here? Is it always necessary?

Comment: It wraps the code that actually calls the `PropertyChanged` event (which is always necessary when you want to update a binding). If you have multiple properties, it's just less code to call this method, instead of rewriting its code in every property setter.

Comment: Thanks, one very noob question :p Is this MVVM right? I've read that I need to have Model/View/ViewModel. Am I using the ViewModel correctly here?

Comment: Your MyViewModel is indeed a view model class, as it defines one or more properties that a view class (your UserControl1) binds to. Hence it is MVVM, although you don't seem to have model layer yet.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, now I'm trying to implement it using ICommand as you suggested.