# Send commands between two usercontrols in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I'm trying to send a command from one `UserControl` to another. The first one contains a button and the second one contains a custom class that derives from the `Border` class.

I want when I click the `Button` in `UserControl` to execute the `Redraw method` in `CustomBorder` in `UserControl2`.

Here is what I have done so far.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="SendCommands.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sendCommands="clr-namespace:SendCommands"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <sendCommands:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <sendCommands:UserControl1 Grid.Row="0"/>
        <sendCommands:UserControl2 Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**UserControl1:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SendCommands.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
            <Button Content="Redraw" 
                    Width="200"
                    Height="30"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl2:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SendCommands.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sendCommands="clr-namespace:SendCommands">
    <Grid>
        <sendCommands:CustomBorder Background="Black">

        </sendCommands:CustomBorder>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**CustomBorder class:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SendCommands
{
    public class CustomBorder : Border
    {
        public void Redraw()
        {
            // Operations to redraw some elements inside the CustomBorder
            MessageBox.Show("We did it!");
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs:**

```
namespace SendCommands
{
    class ViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

Please somebody help me learn this once and for all. I'm new to `MVVM` concept and I have read a lot but no results. I really need a practical solution to get the concepts right.

Comment: Do you have Separate ViewModels for each of these, MainWindow, UserControl1, UserControl2 ?

Further how have they been instantiated.. MainViewModel's instance should have instances of the UserControls ViewModel..

Comment: @bit No, only one `ViewModel.cs` which is for `MainWindow`.

Comment: well, thats not excatly MVVM then.. What you can do is have separate VMs for each of your controls, and which would be instantiated by the MainViewModel (of mainView).. there after you could simply exposed an event from UserControl1 (ButtonClick) to which the UserControl2 would subsrcibe to, and execute Redraw() when that event is fired.. All this happens in the context of the MainViewModel..

Comment: @bit I'm starting to understand this a little bit after your comment. Can you please post the main parts of your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

What does your Redraw method is really supposed to do? Change border if some property has changed? E.g. an item in a shop was sold out?

In general view should reflect changes in the ViewModel. This happens automatically with bindings. View element, such as button, can communicate with ViewModel with Commands.

Therefore your button would look like this:

```
<Button Command={Binding ClickCommand} />
```

In your ViewModel you'll have a

```
public DelegateCommand ClickCommand {get; private set;}
```

and

```
ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteClick);
```

ExecuteClick would update some properties in the view model, e.g. if you have an online shop, set a SoldOut property of bike object to true.

Your view will in turn bind to properties of Bike and change its appearance if some properties change. Changes like text will happen by themselves, more complicated changes can be achieved with converters (e.g. change bckaground to red in SoldOut is true):

```
<Resources>
 <SoldOutToBckgrConverter x:Key="soldOutToBckgrConverter" />
</Resources>
<Label Content={Binding Path=SelectedItem.Model} Background={Binding Path=SelectedItem.SoldOut, Converter={StaticResource soldOutToBckgrConverter}} />
```

SoldOutToBckgrConverter implements IValueConverter and converts True to Red.

Note: SelectedItem is again bound to a list, whose source is bound to sth like ObservableCollection on your ViewModel.

So basically you shouldn't call redraw, it should all redraw itself automatically with commands, changes in VM and bindings.

Update to your comment: that's what I tried to show, given that I understood the purpose of your redraw right. In my example with products and red background for sold items this will look like this:

In your VM:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyProduct> Products {get;set;}
private MyProduct selectedProduct;
public MyProduct SelectedProduct
{
get {return selectedProduct;}
set {
if (selectedProduct != value) {
selectedProducat = value;
RaisePropertyChanged(()=>SelectedProduct;
}
}
}
```

MyProduct has Model property (real world product model, i.e. brand) and SoldOut.

In your View:

```
   <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<Label Content={Binding Path=SelectedItem.Model} Background={Binding Path=SelectedItem.SoldOut, Converter={StaticResource soldOutToBckgrConverter}} />
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now when you click you button, VM changes SelectedProduct and Binding cahnges background (or border..)

Comment: _So basically you shouldn't call redraw, it should all redraw itself automatically with commands, changes in VM and bindings._

Can you please show this to me with a practical example. I'm very lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "CallMethodAction" behavior provided by Expression Blend. Add System.Windows.Interactivity.dll to your project and you can bind the method to event. In your case "ReDraw" method must bound to "Click" event. More information on this [behavior](http://coreclr.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/using-interaction-triggers-in-mvvm/).

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <sendCommands:UserControl1 Grid.Row="0">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="RefreshButtonClick">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="RedrawCustomBorder"
                                     TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=customBorder}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </sendCommands:UserControl1>
    <sendCommands:UserControl2 Grid.Row="1" x:Name="customBorder"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this running. I'm receiving a namespace error.

Comment: Did you add these namespaces? xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;
 assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

Comment: yes I did but it gives me the namespace error. Can you update your code with code for whole mainwindow?

Comment: You should check this link. http://coreclr.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/using-interaction-triggers-in-mvvm/

Comment: I also referenced Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Ok I created the whole thing in Blend and imported it into VS, now I don't get the error. But how I'm going to call the `Redraw` method?